# How to execute batch file using c#?

Tags: c#, batch-file

I create one window application and as per user selection i create one batch file for copy files in one directory to another directory file is created but its not execute i don't know why? please help.

in code i user process class to execute batch file but its through exception at proc.start();
                My code is:

```
            Process proc = null;
            string tempPath = @"C:\Users\jsolanki\Desktop\temp.bat";
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempPath);
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string item in tempList)
            {
                content.Append(string.Format("Copy \"{0}\"  \"{1}\\\" \r\n", item, destPath));

            }

            sw.WriteLine(content);
            sw.Close();

            string batDir = tempPath;
            proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = batDir;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "temp.bat";
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            MessageBox.Show("Copy is Complete");
```

Comment: Check your 'destPath'

Comment: now issue is solve i would to like to thanks Mostafiz :) Thanku

Comment: Be a professional and do things properly. A C# programmer DOES NOT shell to batch files. Here is the MSDN sample https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: ok great, first try to find a same question and solution in here, if no found anything then asks a question :0

Answer (score 0):

```
string tempPath = @"C:\Users\jsolanki\Desktop\temp.bat";
string batDir = tempPath;
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = batDir;
```

Check carefully you have set working directory a file and not a directory.

Also print the exception message.